# Dependent observable to concatenate array items

Tags: knockout.js

http://jsfiddle.net/bWJTY/29/

Can anybody tell me where my dependent observable is going wrong?

```
self.FirstTwo = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.FiveFave.FaveItems[0].Name + " " + self.FiveFave.FaveItems[1].Name;    
}, self);
```

I just want to concatenate the first two items of an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the value of an observable, you need to call it as a function with no arguments.  In your case, `Name` is an observable, so you would have to do:

```
return self.FiveFave.FaveItems[0].Name() + " " + self.FiveFave.FaveItems[1].Name();
```

In bindings, where you are passing a simple observable, Knockout handles unwrapping it for you, which is why you don't have to do things like `text: name()`